# Пытаюсь задать ширину для `v-text-field` и она не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify

Пытаюсь задать ширину для `v-text-field` и она не срабатывает. И не получается разместить этот инпут над карточками, нужно чтоб он был примерно ширинов в 200 пикс. и справа от него не было никаких карточек, чтоб они уже начинались с ряда ниже.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-contaiter class="fill-height">
       <v-row>
        <v-text-field dark label="Добавьте крипту" width="200" persistent-hint
            outlined></v-text-field>
       </v-row>

      <v-row class="mx-4 mt-14 my-auto">
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-card class="text-center">
            <v-card-text class="pb-0">
              BTC
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
              Курс крипты
            </v-card-title>
            <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
              Удалить
              <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-card class="text-center">
            <v-card-text class="pb-0">
              BTC
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
              Курс крипты
            </v-card-title>
            <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
              Удалить
              <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-card class="text-center">
            <v-card-text class="pb-0">
              BTC
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
              Курс крипты
            </v-card-title>
            <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
              Удалить
              <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-card class="text-center">
            <v-card-text class="pb-0">
              BTC
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
              Курс крипты
            </v-card-title>
            <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
              Удалить
              <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-card class="text-center">
            <v-card-text class="pb-0">
              BTC
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
              Курс крипты
            </v-card-title>
            <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
              Удалить
              <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3">
          <v-card class="text-center">
            <v-card-text class="pb-0">
              BTC
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
              Курс крипты
            </v-card-title>
            <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
              Удалить
              <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-contaiter>
  </div>
</template>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте пожалуйста добавить **v-col cols="3"** для v-text-field пример ниже

```
   <template>
   <div>
   <v-contaiter class="fill-height">
    <v-row>
    <v-col
      cols="3"
    >
      <v-text-field></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>

  <v-row class="mx-4 mt-14 my-auto">
    <v-col cols="3">
      <v-card class="text-center">
        <v-card-text class="pb-0">
          BTC
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
          Курс крипты
        </v-card-title>
        <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
          Удалить
          <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
      <v-card class="text-center">
        <v-card-text class="pb-0">
          BTC
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
          Курс крипты
        </v-card-title>
        <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
          Удалить
          <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
      <v-card class="text-center">
        <v-card-text class="pb-0">
          BTC
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
          Курс крипты
        </v-card-title>
        <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
          Удалить
          <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
      <v-card class="text-center">
        <v-card-text class="pb-0">
          BTC
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
          Курс крипты
        </v-card-title>
        <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
          Удалить
          <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
      <v-card class="text-center">
        <v-card-text class="pb-0">
          BTC
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
          Курс крипты
        </v-card-title>
        <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
          Удалить
          <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="3">
      <v-card class="text-center">
        <v-card-text class="pb-0">
          BTC
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 pb-3">
          Курс крипты
        </v-card-title>
        <v-btn color="red" dark small class="mb-3">
          Удалить
          <v-icon right>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-contaiter>
</div>
</template>
```